# Google Sheets API - Python - Constructing Body for BatchUpdate

Tags: python, api, dictionary

I need to create the body for multiple updates to a Google Spreadsheet using Python.

I used the Python dictionary `dict()` but that doesn't work for multiple values that are repeated as `dict()` doesn't allow multiple keys.

My code snippet is:

```
body = {
       }
for i in range (0,len(deltaListcolNames) ):
        rangeItem = deltaListcolNames[i]

        batch_input_value = deltaListcolVals[i]

        body["range"] = rangeItem
        body["majorDimension"] =  "ROWS"
        body["values"] = "[["+str(batch_input_value)+"]]"




batch_update_values_request_body = {
# How the input data should be interpreted.
  'value_input_option': 'USER_ENTERED',   

 # The new values for the input sheet...   to apply to the spreadsheet.
  'data': [
   dict(body)

          ]
}  

print(batch_update_values_request_body)
request = service.spreadsheets().values().batchUpdate(
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, 
    body=batch_update_values_request_body)

response = request.execute()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answer, Graham.
I doubled back and went away from using the dict paradigm and found that by using this grid, I was able to make the data structure.   Here is how I coded it... 
perhaps a bit quirky but it works nicely:

```
range_value_data_list = []

width = 1
#
height = 1
for i in range (0,len(deltaListcolNames) ):
        rangeItem = deltaListcolNames[i]
        # print(" the value for rangeItem is : ", rangeItem)
        batch_input_value = str(deltaListcolVals[i])
        print(" the value for batch_input_value is : ", batch_input_value)
        # construct the data structure for the value
        grid = [[None] * width for i in range(height)]
        grid[0][0] = batch_input_value

        range_value_item_str = { 'range': rangeItem, 'values': (grid) }
        range_value_data_list.append(range_value_item_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Review the documentation for the [Python client library methods](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/python/latest/sheets_v4.spreadsheets.values.html#batchUpdate): The `data` portion is a list of dict objects.

So your construct is close, you just need a loop that fills the data list:

```
data = []
for i in range(0, len(deltaListcolNames)):
    body = {}
    # fill out the body
    rangeItem = deltaListcolNames[i]
    ....

    # Add this update's body to the array with the other update bodies.
    data.append(body)

# build the rest of the request
...
# send the request
...
```